# I am getting an error about my index being out of bounds

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

My code is meant to find the number of times two words intersect at common letters and then print out the two words crossed, if they do cross.

When I compile it is fine but when I run it I get an error. I know that it has to do with my index being out of range but I don't know what to do.

```
public class Assg23
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

            String w1 = args[0];
            String w2 = args[1];

            int numberOfCrosses = 0;

        int pos1 = 0;
            int pos2 = 0;


            for(int i=0; i < w1.length(); i++)
            {
                for(int j=0; j < w2.length(); j++)
                {   
                    if(w1.charAt(i) == w2.charAt(j))
                    {
                        numberOfCrosses++;
                        crossesAt(w1, pos1, w2, pos2);
                        printCross(w1, pos1, w2, pos2);
                    }
                }
            }

        if(numberOfCrosses == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Words do not cross");
        }
    }

    private static boolean crossesAt(String w1, int pos1, String w2, int pos2)
    {
        if(w1.charAt(pos1) == w2.charAt(pos2))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

    private static void printCross(String w1, int pos1, String w2, int pos2)
    {
        for(int i=0; i < w1.length(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < w2.length(); j++)
            {
                if(j == pos1)
                {
                    System.out.print(w2.charAt(i));
                }
                if(i == pos2)
                {   
                    System.out.print(w1.charAt(j));
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }   

            }
        }



    }
```

I am getting this error:

Line 59 is: System.out.print(w2.charAt(i));
Line 27 is: printCross(w1, pos1, w2, pos2);

```
x-10-250-57-156:csci1103 Katie$ java Assg23 lottery boat
blotto    a    t    Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4`
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at Assg23.printCross(Assg23.java:59)
    at Assg23.main(Assg23.java:27)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trace through your printCross algorithm.

The outer loop loops through the length of your first string, w1 - ("lottery"), and your inner loop loops through the length of the second string, w2 - ("boat").

Once your outer loop's index (i) is greater than the length of string w2, you do not want to be accessing w2.charAt(i), which is what you are doing in line `System.out.print(w2.charAt(i));`.

The same applies for line `System.out.print(w1.charAt(j));`, but will only be problematic if j is greater than the length of w1 (ie, if string w1 is shorter than string w2).

I am not entirely sure if I understand what you are trying to do, but you can implement a simple check such as this:

```
if (j == pos1 && i < w2.length()) { ... }
```

Comment: However, you would be better off redesigning your algorithms.

Comment: I am getting this error now when trying to compile after your suggestion @jck `bad operand types for binary operator '&&' first type: boolean second type: char`

Comment: Check your implementation. Second operand should not be a char.

Comment: Using a boolean for both turns it into numbers rather than words @jck

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing. Simply add `&& i < w2.length()` and `&& j < w1.length()` to your if statements.

Comment: I must have been typing it in wrong. It worked now I just have to fix the code so the words are printed out right.